# How Multicast works?

Tags: audio, streaming, multicast

I want to implement a little system that will use the multicast technique to stream audio. I don't know much about it, but I understood it is a very efficient technique for streaming.

What does it require me to do in order to implement such system? And how can I know that my ISP even support it?

Answer (score 1):

Multicasting has to be supported by the network, unfortunately there's a low number of ISPs supporting it, making it pretty much only usable within LAN networks.

There are ISPs supporting it but both the originating and the target ISP need to support it.

To figure out whether your ISP supports multicast your best bet is to check their website, call them, or send them an email[*](https://superuser.com/questions/44479/checking-if-my-isp-supports-ip-multicast)

Comment: In my country there are two types of ISPs. One that provides the infrastructure and one that is connecting me to the internet. Which one should I call?
Is that a hard and sustained process (implement multicast on their network)?

Comment: If one is merely patching you through then I'd say the one providing the infrastructure. Though I'm not sure.

Comment: OK. I'll try to catch one of the techies at the company for a talk.  Thank you.

Comment: Note that the ISP of the person wanting to subscribe is also going to have to support it

Comment: Finally, the ISP responded to my question and it says their network IS supporting Multicast.  What should I do next?

Comment: Unfortunately this is where my knowledge ends, I know the high-level theory. But that's about it. Sorry